# How to control decimals of a float in formatted string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Recently I came upon this awesome way to prevent python from converting floats to scientific notation:

```
start = 0.000005
a = f'{start:.10f}'
print(a)
```

Output:

```
0.0000050000
```

I was wondering if there is an automated way to determine how many decimals the number has instead of providing the amount yourself `.10f` so I can get this output:

```
0.000005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) method to remove the zeros on the right:

```
start = 0.000005
a = f'{start:.10f}'.rstrip('0')
print(a)
# 0.000005
```

In case you have no decimal part, it could be better to also remove the '.' when there is no zero left:

```
start = 5.00000
a = f'{start:.10f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')
print(a)
# 5
```

Comment: This is a workaround that works but it still requires the decimal precision from the user. I was hoping there was a way to automate this. Thanks though. I will accept this answer if there will be no better one

Answer (score -1):

just use `print(f'{start:f})` without specyfing how many decimal points you want

Comment: This will only print the first 6 decimals